# Basis of all real polynomials?

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, vectors, vector-analysis

I am studying the book *Topics in Algebraic Graph Theory* by Beineke et all and the page 12. By the book, the set of all real polynomials can be generated by the set $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ which I understand such that

$$\mathbb{R}[x]=\langle1,x,x^{2},\ldots\rangle$$

where I want to make sure that I have understood the notation correctly.

**Is my notation $\mathbb R[x]$ correct for all real polynomials? So $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ spans $\mathbb R[x]$?**

*Examples. Correct?*

1. Which vector space does the $\{ x \}$ span? Not vector space, multiplicative identity not in $\{ x\}$.
2. Size changing like this?

   2. $\langle 1 \rangle=\mathbb R$ is the smallest vector space while
   3. $\langle 1,x\rangle$ is a little bit larger, then
   4. $\langle 1,x,x^2,\ldots\rangle=\mathbb R[x]$ would be the largest.
3. $x^2\not\in\langle 1,x,x^{11}\rangle$
4. $\langle 1,x\rangle=\mathbb R[x] / \langle 1, x^2,x^3,\ldots\rangle$ (the first vector space complemented with the second)?

Comment: Yes, the vector space of all real polynomials is spanned by $1,x,x^2,\ldots,$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}$ is real numbers and the vector space of all real polynomial is spanned by the monomials. But I do not know if polynomials are written with $[x]$ like that.

Comment: yes that is the standard notation :)

Comment: No, the basis is $(e_1,e_2,e_3, e_4\ldots ,)=(1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots )$ of infinite length. For example, $3x^3+x-7=3e_4+e_2-7e_1$.

Comment: For the span of $\{x\}$, why do we need multiplicative identities?

Comment: @pjs36 by [condition 8](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html) about scalar multiplicative identity that must be in the basis?

Comment: That condition, and any axiom for a vector space, is silent about bases. It just says that if you hit a vector $v$ with the multiplicative identity scalar $1$, you get back $v$, and that's true of $\operatorname{Span}(x) = \{cx : c \in \Bbb R\}$. I think the source of confusion may be distinguishing between the scalar $1 \in \Bbb R$ and the vector $1 \in \Bbb R[x]$. The vector space of polynomials is atypical in that it caries a natural ring structure: We *can* multiply polynomials (although not vectors, in general. If you can, you have a very special kind of vector space, an *algebra*).